# How to change a character in multiple .txt-files and save/ overwrite the existing file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, file

i'm really new to Powershell (2 days) and i am not good yet. :(

My Question ist:
**How to change a character in multiple .txt-files and save/ overwrite the existing file in Powershell**

My goal is to Copy multiple RAW-Files in a new folder, change the file-name from .tsv to .txt and at least change one character in these files from % to percent.

What i've got so far:
The first two steps are working, but i'm losing my mind with the third step (the replacement).

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\RAW\*.tsv" -Destination "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TXT" -Recurse
Set-Location "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TXT"
Get-ChildItem *.tsv | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.tsv','.txt' }
```

This works fine for me and now i am not able to get further ...
I am able to replace the "%" in one specific file, and save it in a new file, but this doesn't work for a batch processing with changing file-names.

```
$file = "A.txt"
Get-Content $file  | Foreach {$_ -replace "%", "percent"}  | Set-Content A_1.txt
```

It would be perfect, if "*$file = "A.txt"*" would be "*all the files in this path with .txt*" and
"*Set-Content A_1.txt*" would be "*overwrite the existing file*".

I hope someone will help me, thank you! <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have some of the solution in your first code snippet, you need to iterate over the files again to perform the replace and save.

```
$txtFiles = Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt

ForEach ($file in $txtFiles) {
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '%','percent'
    } | Set-Content $file
}
```

The first line adds all the text files to an array, the foreach loop iterates over the files of the array and grabs the content of the file and **unloads it** - that's the reason for the parenthesis, the Foreach-Object then iterates over the content of the file and saves it to the same file name as before.

If you skip the parentheses around `Get-Content $file` the file would still be loaded into memory and you would get an error message about not being able to save the file.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was thinking about a way like this, but i wasn't able to get it done! Thank you! <3